# Add panels to site dynamically

Tags: development, 2013

I have a main panel which is called `linksAndPicturesPanel` within this panel, I want to add more panels -> 1 panel for the link and 1 panel for a picture (red and green). 
[image]Furthermore, it should be possible to add multiple links and pictures. To add those panels I use this code:

```
 Panel linkPanel = new Panel();
 linkPanel.CssClass = "linkList";
 linkPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("blablabla -----"));

 Panel picturePanel = new Panel();
 picturePanel.CssClass = "pictureFromLink";
 picturePanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("blablabla22222 -----"));

 linksAndPicturesPanel.Controls.Add(linkPanel);
 linksAndPicturesPanel.Controls.Add(picturePanel);
```

This works fine for one line. After adding multiple lines, the page reloads and all lines exept the last one are gone. Is there a way, to prevent a page reload so that there all added items will be displayed ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [ASP:UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint UI is built as a Web Application. Web Application are Stateless and that is the reason why controls you are generating dynamically are lost on `postback`.

To eliminate this you should handle the `Page_Load` event and create the controls.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Panel linkPanel = new Panel();
    linkPanel.CssClass = "linkList";
    linkPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("blablabla -----"));

    Panel picturePanel = new Panel();
    picturePanel.CssClass = "pictureFromLink";
    picturePanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("blablabla22222 -----"));

    linksAndPicturesPanel.Controls.Add(linkPanel);
    linksAndPicturesPanel.Controls.Add(picturePanel);
 }
```

Also you should use `Session` for saving the data during postback.